# Getting WP Functions to Return rather than Printing Immediately

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to build an array within "The Loop" of values provided from various functions like `the_title()`, `the_excerpt()`, `the_permalink()` and others. I'd like to do something similar to what follows. The unfortunate thing is that most of these functions immediately print their results rather than returning them. Furthermore, I have checked the available parameters for these, and haven't found any option to force a return.

```
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $items[] = array(
      "id" => get_the_id(), "the_title" => the_title(), 
      "the_excerpt" => the_excerpt(), "the_permalink" => the_permalink()
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Alternative Functions with Guessable Names

There are apparently a couple different ways to tackle this issue. As noted earlier, some functions will come with an alternative function that merely prepends "get_" to the beginning. For instance `the_title()` prints the title, whereas `get_the_title()` returns the title.

#### Alternative Functions with Less-Guessable Names

Other functions don't follow this practice. For instance, `the_permalink()` has no alternative called `get_the_permalink()`. Instead, its alternative is simply `get_permalink()`. This can be confusing, so I reccomend you perform look-ups on the [Template Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) page.

#### The Occasional Boolean Parameter (Not Common to all functions)

Additionally, some functions will contain a parameter which allows you to alter the normal behavior. For instance, if you don't wish to use `get_the_title()`, you could simply use the following:

```
<?php $title = the_title('echo=0'); ?>
```

This sets the boolean value to false, meaning the value will be returned rather than echo'd.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of the Wordpress functions like `the_*()` have alternatives like `get_the_*()` which do exactly this.

Comment: That is true for some, but not for others like `the_permalink()`

Comment: I just downloaded WP 2.8.4 and there is a function get_permalink() in link-template.php and the_permalink() uses this funtion.

Comment: @VolkerK Thank you. What better case for consistent-naming than this :)